# What is the proper expression for 'putting down the hood' (of a sweatshirt)?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

Alright, super simple question I guess, but I'm no native speaker and google doesn't seem to be helpful here...

What do you call it when you go from wearing your hoodie 'hood up' to 'hood down (open?)'

thanks a bunch

Comment: Putting your hood down?

Answer (score 3):

You would be [***un-hooding***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/un-hood?s=t) yourself I guess? Although you would definitely need to establish context lest you be seriously misinterpreted.

You could also [***doff***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/doff?s=t) or [***shuck***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/shuck?s=t) the hood